# Пакеты в ос linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Как оформить написанный скрипт в виде пакета?

Comment: О каких пакетах речь?

Comment: В виде репозитория может?

Comment: Если deb пакет, то вот подробная инструкция https://habrahabr.ru/post/78094/

Comment: *Как оформить написанный скрипт в виде пакета?* — абсолютно точно так же, как и любую другую программу.

Comment: для какой цели пакет создать? Чтобы легко удалить, можно checkinstall использовать. Чтобы в дистрибутив добавить, обычно cargo-culting приходится, используя похожие уже принятые проекты (и инструменты и правила могут меняться от выпуска к выпуску).  Иногда достаточно простой команды типа: `python setup.py --command-packages=stdeb.command bdist_deb` или [fpm](http://fpm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use-cases/files.html) как альтерантива dockerу для лёгкой установки/запуска команды.  Это очень обширный вопрос.

Comment: @VladSpirin Не надо его дубликатить. Вчера был более узкий вопрос (как создать скрипт + как создать пакет), явная домашка сделай-за-меня. А текущий вопрос идеален, разве что ответ будет слишком длинным и поэтому его всё равно прихлопнут, но уж лучше с правильной причиной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## предупреждение: так делать не надо!

т.к. в метках упомянут дистрибутив *ubuntu*, скажу пару слов про «псевдо-пакетирование» программы в deb-пакет (естественно, в разрезе дистрибутива *debian gnu/linux*, а не *ubuntu*, его прямого «наследника»).

вообще правильный путь пакетирования изложен в [Debian New Maintainers' Guide](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/index.html), раздел [First steps](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/first.html).

но для создания примитивного и совершенно «неправильного» (с точки зрения [дистрибутивной политики](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/index.html)) пакета вполне можно поступить проще, воспользовавшись программой [*dpkg-deb*](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/dpkg/dpkg-deb.1.en.html).

1. предположим, что у нас в текущем каталоге есть файл с именем `myscript`:

   ```
   $ cat myscript
   #!/bin/sh
   echo hello from $0

   $ chmod +x myscript
   $ ./myscript
   hello from ./myscript
   ```
2. формировать содержимое пакета мы будем в каталоге `pkg` (имя произвольно). сначала скопируем туда скрипт:

   ```
   $ install -D myscript pkg/usr/local/bin/myscript
   ```
3. затем приложим туда минимального содержимого «control-файл» с описанием пакета:

   ```
   $ cat control 
   Package: myscript
   Version: 0.0
   Architecture: all
   Description: myscript
   $ install -D control pkg/DEBIAN/control
   ```
4. получилось такое содержимое каталога `pkg`:

   ```
   $ tree pkg
   pkg
   ├── DEBIAN
   │   └── control
   └── usr
       └── local
           └── bin
               └── myscript

   4 directories, 2 files
   ```
5. теперь сделаем из этих «ошмётков» файл с пакетом:

   ```
   $ dpkg-deb -b pkg myscript.deb
   dpkg-deb: warning: parsing file 'pkg/DEBIAN/control' near line 5 package 'myscript':
    missing maintainer
   dpkg-deb: warning: ignoring 1 warning about the control file(s)
   dpkg-deb: building package 'myscript' in 'myscript.deb'.
   ```
6. проверим «устанавливаемость» и работоспособность:

   ```
   $ docker run --rm -ti -v $(pwd):/root debian:9 sh -c 'dpkg -i /root/myscript.deb && myscript'
   dpkg: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/control' near line 5 package 'myscript':
    missing maintainer
   Selecting previously unselected package myscript.
   (Reading database ... 6491 files and directories currently installed.)
   Preparing to unpack /root/myscript.deb ...
   Unpacking myscript (0.0) ...
   Setting up myscript (0.0) ...
   hello from /usr/local/bin/myscript
   ```

всё. слепленная нами из дерьма пуля таки умудрилась куда-то попасть!

Comment: я бы не ставил в /usr/local потому что мы ж в пакете, а не локальная установка

Comment: @eri, боюсь, это не единственное нарушение debian policy, которое присутствует в моём ответе.

Comment: что означает эта команда?
docker run --rm -ti -v $(pwd):/root debian:9 sh -c 'dpkg -i /root/myscript.deb && myscript'

Comment: это изврещение для проверки работает ли dpkg)